# MSSQL on ECS with EFS (NFS) Drive Performance?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I've a single container hosting an MSSQL instance. I'm streaming a ~90Mb Gzip CSV via a Lambda from S3 and writing a large amount of inserts in a transaction.

So far the lambda has taken 5 minutes but I have larger files then this and will likely exceed the 15 minute lambda timeout.

I'm thinking that the mounted EFS drive inside the docker container will be an IO bottleneck. Anyone ran into this before? I'm also unsure what the outcome of ECS starting a second container with both MSSQL instances using the same data folder would be.

Comment: Are you using a Bulk Copy API, or inserting row-by-row?

Comment: I've an ongoing discussion here - 

https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1363

As the bulk-write seems to need to know the schema up-front and doesn't support streaming.

The uncompressed ~600Mb CSV has 645,455 records and exceeds the 15m lambda run-time.

Comment: Without a proper bulk API you can batch a few 100s of rows in JSON and use OPENJSON to shred and insert them.  It’s surprisingly fast.

Comment: EFS is generally a HUGE IO bottleneck. You would have to setup provisioned throughput on the EFS volume, but even then it's going to be real slow compared normal disk volume. Why do you feel the need to run MSSQL off an EFS volume? Why not use RDS? Or at least run it off an EBS volume?  If you absolutely have to run this off an NFS mounted drive, then Amazon FSx is much more appropriate than EFS.

Comment: I'm stuck with MSSQL due to legacy work. I'm currently entering 130k inserts in 4m. I turned EFS off but it hasn't made a noticeable difference. Logging mode is 'SIMPLE' now too.

The container is running on ECE Fargate, I'll google now if FSx is supported but didn't see it as an option. The reason for the NFS mount was rebuilding the image (updating the task) would otherwise destroy the data.

Comment: @MarkB, given my data is flat csv like is there a table type equivalent to openjson?

Comment: You really shouldn't run databases on Fargate. You basically picked the least performant way to run a database on AWS. Just run it on an EC2 instance if you want to manage it yourself. As to being stuck with MSSQL, AWS RDS offers managed MSSQL.

Comment: I didn't know RDS for MSSQL existed, looking into that as a first port of call. Thank you!

Comment: Using MSSQL on RDS and it's actually slower, about 5k records per 6 seconds. I'll have to switch to bulk upload.